# SQL parameters for dynamic size deletes and inserts

Tags: c#, sql

I have a service that copies data and does modifications etc. One of the functions is just straight replicating deletes and inserts across the databases which is fine and easily accomplished using Entity, unfortunately larger queries become quite slow so I'm looking to just run it as a raw SQL query.

This is now taking the form of a foreach loop, and building up the query based on what feeds through

i.e

```
if(deletes.Count() > 0) 
{
    // Build up delete string
    StringBuilder sqlCommand = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM RandomTable WHERE ");

    List<string> rows = new List<string>();

    foreach(var item in query)
    {
        rows.Add(string.Format("(Key1 = '{0}' AND Key2 = '{1}' AND Key3 = '{2}' AND Key4 = '{3}' AND Key5 = '{4}')",
                               item.Key1, item.Key2, item.Key3, item.Key4, item.Key5));
    }

    sqlCommand.Append(string.Join(" OR ", rows));
    sqlCommand.Append(";");
    runyoubadthing(sqlCommand);
}
```

(please note, I am stripping quotes and junk, but not needed for this example) Now I know that they need to be parameterized (however the above is in a service that just talks between databases so technically shouldn't need it, but I'd still like to follow good practice).

My question is: how would I do the above in proper parameterized query where it could run as a single query instead of running as thousands of single deletes which would take a hell of a lot longer?

Side note: this whole ordeal would be about 1000 times better with a single auto incrementing ID, unfortunately this is not my database and now I have to deal with up to 10 primary key nightmares for finding unique data

Comment: If your database supports it, you can use Table valued parameters instead of sending each value in a different parameter. This way, you can delete (or insert) a full set instead of a single row each time. However, note that this will also mean that if one delete (or insert) fails, everything sent in that data table fails with it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The db is sql server 2005, from the documentation about table valued parameters seems to start 2008. Attempted a trial run but with a failure which was a bit of a bugger. I might look at turning the whole thing to straight datatables and checking the speed of that instead

Comment: You are correct. Table valued parameters started in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var Command = new SQLCommand {
    CommandText = "DELETE FROM RandomTable WHERE ",
    Connection = yourConnection
};
var count = 0;
foreach(var item in query)
{
    Command.CommandText += Command.CommandText.EndsWith("WHERE ")? "": "OR ";
    Command.CommandText += $"(Key1 = '@{count}0' AND Key2 = '@{count}1' AND Key3 = '@{count}2' AND Key4 = '@{count}3' AND Key5 = '@{count}4')";
    Command.Parameters.Add($"@{count}0", [YourDBType]).Value = item.Key1;
    Command.Parameters.Add($"@{count}1", [YourDBType]).Value = item.Key2;
    Command.Parameters.Add($"@{count}2", [YourDBType]).Value = item.Key3;
    Command.Parameters.Add($"@{count}3", [YourDBType]).Value = item.Key4;
    Command.Parameters.Add($"@{count}4", [YourDBType]).Value = item.Key5;
    count++;
}
Command.Prepare();
//Execute Command
```

I don't think that there is any better way to solve this problem other than executing a delete command for each item.

Comment: You need to increment `count` within the `foreach` loop. And it's preferable to use a `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation within a loop.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have the single quotes around the parameter names.

Comment: Thanks @Nullpointer I worked out in the most horrible way i could that the string builder (and your answer) are best for the bulk delete, and datatable bulkinsert for inserts, which now means i have entity pulling data, parameters deleting and datatables inserting, im pretty sure the next programmer to look at this will find my home address and assault me with a brick

Comment: @NullPointer Almost worked nicely, unfortunately the deletes can have anywhere from 10 to 100,000 deletes at any time, and there are some tables with 14 keys which means 14 parameters, while the SQL parameters max out at 2100. To cope i can chuck it in a while loop that repeats every 500 or so times but then each command will need to be adjusted based on number of keys. I think i might Go back to square one and attempt a full rebuild with just datatables just not sure on overall speeds.